# Invariant $\sigma$-algebras and Skew-Products

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

$\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$ $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$
Let $(X, \mc X, \mu)$ be a probability space and $G$ be a countable group.
Let $T:G\times X\to X$ be a measure preserving action of $G$ on $X$.
Let $\nu$ be a probability measure on $G$ such that the support of $\nu$ contains a generating set of $G$.
Equip $G^\Z$ with the probability measure $\nu^\Z$ and let $\sigma:G^\Z\to G^\Z$ be the shift map.
We will write an element of $G^\Z$ as $g = (g_n)_{n\in \Z}$.

We define a map $\Phi:X\times G^\Z\to X\times G^\Z$ as
$$
\Phi(x, g) = (T^{g_0}x, \sigma(g))
$$
By Fubini's theorem it follows that $\Phi$ preserves the measure $\mu\times \nu^{\Z}$.

Let $\mc I$ be the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ consisting of all the $G$-invariant subsets of $X$.

> **Question.**
> Can we describe the $\sigma$-algebra of $\Phi$-invariant subsets of $X\times G^{\mathbb Z}$ in terms of $\mc I$.

It is clear that for any $A\in \mc I$ we have $A\times G^\Z$ is $\Phi$-invariant.
Perhaps these are all the $\Phi$-invariant subsets.
The question is important since in order to get interesting information by applying ergodic theorems to the map $\Phi$ it would be useful to know the $\Phi$-invariant $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I'm assuming that you meant $Y = G^{\mathbb{Z}}$. With no additional restrictions, the $\sigma$-algebra of $\Phi$-invariant sets can be finer than $\mathcal{X} \otimes \{ Y \}$. Let $E \subset X$ be a set with $T$-stabilizer $\mathrm{Stab}(E)$ a proper subgroup of $G$ (I mean $\mathrm{Stab}(E)$ stabilizes $E$ as a set, not pointwise). Then $E \times \mathrm{Stab}(E)^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is $\Phi$-invariant and is not of the form $A \times G^{\mathbb{Z}}$. You might want to consider a minimal action $T$ on a compact $X$, for instance, to get rid of examples like this and see if you can find others.

Comment: @SophieMacDonald You are right. But I think one should identify sets up to measure 0. If $\text{Stab}(E)$ is not full measure in $G$ then $\text{Stab}(E)^{\mathbb Z}$ has measure $0$ in $G^{\mathbb Z}$. Thus $E\times \text{Stab}(E)^{\mathbb Z}$ can be identified with $E\times \emptyset$. If $\text{Stab}(E)$ has full measure then $E\times \text{Stab}(E)^{\mathbb Z}$ can be identified with $E\times G^{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: OK, interesting. I don't have an answer either way, but I'll continue playing with it. (I have my candidacy exam coming up and really need to tighten up my ergodic theory with questions like this!) The simplest example is where $G$ is a finite group acting componentwise by $T$ on $X = G^{\mathbb{Z}} = Y$. For instance, $G= \mathbb{F}_2$ gives the full $2$-shift. Is the answer obvious even in this setting?

Comment: @SophieMacDonald I think it is true for $F_2$, I asked a friend and he gave me a complicated proof. I will post it in some time while waiting for a more elementary answer. Meanwhile, best of luck for your candy.